# Specifying the location of .bowerrc when calling bower install

Tags: dependencies, npm, bower

I have a parent project that contains a child module. The module has its own `bower.json`  which specifies the module dependencies and `.bowerrc`which specifies which folder these should be downloaded into. These dependencies are linked in the module HTML.

The parent project uses `package.json` to manage Node dependencies.

To prevent users having to run both `npm install` (for the parent dependencies) and `cd module`, `bower install`, `cd ../` (for the module dependencies), I have added a `postinstall` script to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "./node_modules/.bin/bower install ./module/ --config.directory=\"./module/public/bower_components\""
}
```

Note that the only way that I could get Bower to install the module's dependencies into `/module/public/bower_components` was to explicitly state the `directory` in the `postinstall` script.

However `./module/.bowerrc` already contains this information, so ideally I'd like to 'make' the `bower install` aware of this. This would also make `package.json` easier to maintain and `module` more portable.

I've also tried transferring the Bower dependency and `postinstall` script into my module's `package.json`, using the `postinstall` hook in the parent's `package.json` to run `npm install` in the module directory. But this approach ends in module. dependencies being downloaded into the parent's `node_modules` folder.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need two package managers? Maybe you can stick to npm?

Comment: @GrimurD could you please accept the answer if it solves this problem

Answer (score 3):

Bower config uses the following order of precedence to resolve configurations for the build.

From bower docs at http://bower.io/docs/config/

- CLI arguments via --config
- Environment variables
- Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
- All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
- .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (~)
- .bowerrc file located in the global folder (/)

In your case you can put a .bowerrc file in the same folder as package.json but configure all the properties with prefix module/public to get your setup working.

I do like your idea of managing all the dependencies from one place in package.json.